# D3 transition working on "background-color" but not on "width"

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, bar-chart, transition

Simple problem: I'm trying to code an animated bar chart inside a `<div id="chart"></div`with the following d3.js code:

```
data=[100,200,400,350];
d3.select("#chart")
.selectAll("div")
.data(data)
.enter()
.append("div")
  .style("height",30)
  .style("width",function(d){return d/2})
  .style("background-color","grey")
  .transition()
    .style("width",function(d){return d})
    .style("background-color","blue");
```

The result is pretty weird: the bars colors go from `grey` to `red` as expected, but their width stay at `d/2`.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting widths using a css style.  This requires [units](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width) (px, em, or %).

Updated code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="d3@4.0.0" data-semver="4.0.0" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="chart"></div>
  <script>
    data = [100, 200, 400, 350];
    d3.select("#chart")
      .selectAll("div")
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append("div")
      .style("height", "30px")
      .style("width", function(d) {
        return d / 2 + "px"
      })
      .style("background-color", "grey")
      .transition()
      .duration(2000)
      .style("width", function(d) {
        return d + "px";
      })
      .style("background-color", "blue");
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```